# unityでandroid(SO-02J)にビルドした際に、3Dモデルの外観が変わってしまう

Tags: android, unity3d, build

簡単な洋服を着せた人物の3Dモデルについて、タイトルの件発生しております。

UNITY上のPLAYで確認した際には洋服に対して、洋服の下に位置する肌がはみ出る事は無いのですが、androidにbuildをし、android上で確認すると、肌が前面に位置しているはずの洋服からはみ出てしまう（肌の方が洋服よりも一部前に出てしまう）現象が起きています。

何らかの最適化がかかってしまっているのかと思い、Build&Settingにて、Optimization項を色々と無効にしたりと試したのですが、効果はなく。
なんらかの解決に至るための情報をご教示いただきたく、よろしくお願いします。

特に、PLAY画面で確認した内容と異なる内容がandroidに出力されるため、二度手間となってしまい困っております。何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

「Zファイティング」ですか?

とりあえず、(既にやっているかもしれませんが)洋服を肌より浮かす事。
よっぽどカメラが近くによらない限りは、1cmほどあいていても気にはならないはずです。
(気になるかどうか、最終判断は質問者さんが決める事ですが)

あとは、カメラのClippingPlanesの値を調整します。
とりあえず実験で、他のオブジェクトはクリップされてもいいので、問題の服と肌がクリッピングされない程度にNearとFarの値を近づけてください。
これで現象が起きなければ、デプスバッファの精度の問題です。

できる限りNearは遠くに、Farは近くに設定して、NearとFarの差を狭めるべきです。
とりわけ、Nearを遠くに設定すると効果的だと、[Unityのマニュアル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.1/Manual/class-Camera.html)にも書かれています。